# В TreeMap загружается два одинаковых ключа с разными значениями

Tags: java, многопоточность, коллекции

Создаю TreeMap

```
final public static TreeMap<Object, Integer> map = new TreeMap();
```

и в потоке начинают подгружаться данные

```
hread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                while (true) {
...
addtoMap(el.getAttribute("href"),1,map);
...
try {
                                lock.unlock();
                                Thread.sleep(100000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
}
...
//Добавление в map
   public static synchronized void addtoMap(Object o ,Integer key,TreeMap map){
    if((map.containsKey(o) == true) & key==2) {
        map.remove(o);
        map.put(o + "\n", key);
     }
  else if (map.containsKey(o) == false) {
      map.put(o + "\n", key);
  }
}
```

Первый поток засыпает, и работу начинает другой поток, который берет из карты элемент и меняет значение элемента.

```
addtoMap(element,2,map);
```

2 поток добавляет элементы в карту меняя их значение на 2, когда 1 поток просыпается и снова начинает добавлять в карту новые элементы, в map добавляются как новые элементы, так и ключи, которые уже находятся в карте, но с другим значением (в моем случае 1).

В документации написано, что в карте может содержаться только одно значение ключа.

Может кто-нибудь знает как исправить ???

Comment: Вы проверяете на один ключ `map.containsKey(o)`, а добавляете другой `map.put(o + "\n", key)`. Не надо сравнивать так  `map.containsKey(o) == true`,  `containsKey` возвращает boolean.

Comment: И так, между делом: `== true` можно попросту удалить, а `map.containsKey(o) == false` заменить на `!map.containsKey(o)`. Также использовать `&` вместо `&&` нужно осознанно, иначе это может плохо кончиться.

Comment: Еще замечание небольшое. Используйте ConcurrentSkipListMap, вместо TreeMap. Это тоже отсортированная по ключам мэпа.у метода удалите synchronized а в теле вместо if'ов напишите просто map.put(key,value), удалять не обязательно, т.к. если ключи равны то предыдущее значение при вставке просто затирается